# Chart content not getting displayed in ionic

Tags: canvas, ionic-framework, chart.js, angular-chart

I have installed and included scripts for angualr-chart.js and chart.js . I have injected chart.js in my module and defined following in my dashboardCtrl

```
    self.pie= {};
    self.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    self.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    self.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
```

I have the following in my html file

```
        <div class = "col no-padding">
            <div class="card card-pie-chart no-padding">
               <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                  <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="dashboardCtrl.data" labels="dashboardCtrl.labels" legend="true" series="dashboardCtrl.series" options="{showTooltips: false}"></canvas>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The output is as follows there are no errors in console. Note that I can access my data from controller in the Html files.[[image: The middle is my canvas card]] The middle is my canvas card which is overflowing[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Kpy.png)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem. This is what I was missing the prefix chart before every tag.

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-pie" chart-colors="dashboardCtrl.labelColors" chart-data="dashboardCtrl.data" chart-labels="dashboardCtrl.labels" legend="true" chart-series="dashboardCtrl.series" chart-options="{showTooltips: false}"></canvas>
```